# Clickhouse MergeTree family for specific update case

Tags: python, clickhouse

I am thinking on a solution for specific update case in Clickhouse.

Lets say i have table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS guardicore.incidents
(
`id` UUID,
`name` Nullable(String),
`surname` Nullable(String),
`count` Uint32,
`start_time` Nullable(DateTime64(6)),
)
ENGINE = ReplacingMergeTree()
PARTITION BY toDate(start_time)
ORDER BY id
```

First time i write

```
('123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426614174000', 'John', 'Doe', 1, '2024-01-01 08:00:00'),
```

Second time i write

```
('123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426614174000', NULL, NULL, 32, NULL),
```

And in DB i want at the end to have

```
('123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426614174000', 'John', 'Doe', 32, '2024-01-01 08:00:00'),
```

All values should be from first write and only count from the next writes.
Can i do this during the write operation or it could be done only on query SELECT?
I was thinking about ReplaceMergeTree, but seems like it is not a solution.

Comment: The solution is going to depend on the rate of inserts. If there are alot of changes, you will need to move the work to query time. You might be best using a refreshable materialized view (added in 23.12) to store the final stage and periodically compute. This will make the actual SELECT performant from multiple clients. This will require you to accept some latency on the final answer though.